# Declarative interpretation of a non-deterministic automaton simulation

Tags: prolog, declarative

The following Prolog program simulates a non-deterministic automaton:

```
final(s3).

trans(s1,a,s2).
trans(s1,b,s1).
trans(s2,b,s3).
trans(s3,b,s4).

silent(s2,s4).
silent(s3,s1).

accepts(State,[]) :- final(State).

accepts(State, [X|Rest]) :- trans(State,X,State1),
                            accepts(Stat1,Rest).

accepts(State, Rest) :- silent(State, State1),
                        accepts(State1, Rest).
```

Ok I have 3 different kinds of facts:

The first one say me that **s3** is a **final state** (a state of acceptance)
The second typology of facts specify the transition of automaton that read a character of a string.

For example: if I am in the state s1 and the character a is read then it can pass to the state s2.

The third one specify the null transition: that is an arbitrary transition from a state to an other state that don't need an input character.

For example:

```
silent(s2,s4)
```

specify that the automaton can arbitrarily pass from s2 to s4 without reading nothing.

Ok, now I have the rule that specify how pass from a state to another state and how say if it is an acceptance state.

The first rile is:

```
accepts(State,[]) :- final(State).
```

and it say that: **the empty string [], is accepted from a State if this state it is a final state.**

The second rule is:

```
accepts(State, [X|Rest]) :- trans(State,X,State1),
                            accepts(State1,Rest).
```

say that: **the string it is NOT EMPTY and this string it's accepted from the current state State if reading the first symbol X of the string the automaton can pass into some state State1 and the Rest of the string is accepted from State1.**

The third rule is:

```
accepts(State, Rest) :- silent(State, State1),
                        accepts(State1, Rest).
```

and it say that: **a string is accepted from a State if the automaton can make silent move from the current state State to another state State1 and the state State1 can accept the whole input string.**

So if, in the Prolog shell, I perform the statement:

```
accepts(s1,[a,a,a,b]).
```

the response is **true**

but, what is exactly means?

**It means that the s1 state accepts the [a,a,a,b] string because there are a number of transitions of the automaton that I bring from the initial state s1 to a state of acceptance s3?**

A second doubt it is related to an example shown on the book.

On the book perform this query (that obtain all the sequence of 3 character that from s1 bring to the final state s3) and obtain the following output:

```
?- accepts(s1, [X1,X2,X3]).

X1 = a
X2 = a
X3 = b;

X1 = b
X2 = a
X3 = b;

no
```

This is reasonable but if I try to perform it on my Prolog shell I obtain this output:

```
11 ?- accepts(s1, [X1,X2,X3]).
X1 = X2, X2 = a,
X3 = b ;
X1 = X3, X3 = b,
X2 = a ;
false.
```

Why?

Comment: ok...maybe the last output have the same means of the book output...

Comment: to your first question: Yes, that is what it means. To your second question: there's no problem there. `{X1 = X2, X2 = a, X3 = b}` is the same as `{X1 = a, X2 = a, X3 = b}`. `X1` is `X2`, but `X2 is `a`, so `X1` is `a` too. That's just different ways in which different implementations of Prolog report their results. But essentially it is the same.

Answer (score 2):

First of all I get a singleton variable warning when I consult your code (variable name `Stat1`). When I correct it, the list `[a,a,a,b]` is (correctly, assuming the transitions you state) no longer accepted. Also, I rewrote your code slightly to also take the final state into the relation:

```
automaton(State, State, []) :- final(State).
automaton(State0, State, [X|Xs]) :-
        trans(State0, X, State1),
        automaton(State1, State, Xs).
automaton(State0, State, Rest) :-
        silent(State0, State1),
        automaton(State1, State, Rest).
```

The variable naming scheme `Var0, Var1, ..., Var`, where `Var0` means the initial state in some context and `Var` denotes a final state, is a generally useful naming pattern when describing state transitions in Prolog. You can now use this relation to see which final state was reached in the automaton (in your example, it is of course always the unique final state `s3`):

```
?- automaton(s1, State, Xs).
State = s3,
Xs = [a, b] ;
State = s3,
Xs = [a, b, a, b] ;
State = s3,
Xs = [a, b, a, b, a, b] .
```

And to your last question: Yes, you are correct, the answers are declaratively equivalent, SWI Prolog only writes them differently (`X = a, Y = a` is declaratively equivalent to `X = Y, X = a`).

**EDIT**: You can generalize this idea: In the following code, I'm using DCGs to describe the sequence of state transitions that lead to the final state:

```
automaton(State, []) --> { final(State) }.
automaton(State0, [X|Xs]) -->
        [{State0,X}->State1],
        { trans(State0, X, State1) },
        automaton(State1, Xs).
automaton(State0, Rest) -->
        [State0->State1],
        { silent(State0, State1) },
        automaton(State1, Rest).
```

Example:

```
?- length(Xs, _), phrase(automaton(s1, Xs), Ts).
Xs = [a, b],
Ts = [ ({s1, a}->s2), ({s2, b}->s3)] ;
Xs = [b, a, b],
Ts = [ ({s1, b}->s1), ({s1, a}->s2), ({s2, b}->s3)] ;
Xs = [a, b, a, b],
Ts = [ ({s1, a}->s2), ({s2, b}->s3), (s3->s1), ({s1, a}->s2), ({s2, b}->s3)] .
```